# Flutter GetX pass data to another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

I have a flutter app whereby I capture data using a textformfield in a screen. I have a second screen where I would like to display the data that I have captured from the text form field in the first screen.

But first I want to print it to the terminal, from the Second Screen controller, and see what has been passed. I have tried using using GetX naviagtion and passing but I get this error

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

This is the text form field I use to get data as input

```
TextFormField(
                      controller: controller._phoneNumberController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      validator: (value) => validatePhoneNumber(value!),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: accentColor,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular',
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Phone Number",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: Colors.black45,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        fillColor: Color(0xffEBEDF4),
                        filled: true,
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff1D275C),
                          ),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: formFieldColor,
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

This is the method I use to send data to the next page

```
GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Get.to(SecondPage(), arguments: [
                                  controller._phoneNumberController.text
                                ]);
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color(0xffEF5E41),
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(right: 130),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Proceed",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color(0xffFCFCFC),
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                                          color: Color(0xffFCFCFC),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

This is where I try to print the data sent from the first page

```
  dynamic argumentData = Get.arguments;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    print(argumentData[0]);
    super.onInit();
  }
```

How can I fix this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you have an accepted answer here but just want to chime in with a different and arguably easier way that doesn't involve passing arguments around or keys.

Any `TextEditingController` that lives in a GetX class is accessible from anywhere.

Add a listener and store that value into a variable.

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  RxString controllerText = ''.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    textController.addListener(() {
      controllerText.value = textController.text;
    });
  }
}
```

You can test this with a couple simple pages.

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = '/page1';
  final controller = Get.put(Controller());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            TextField(controller: controller.textController),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(Page2.id),
              child: Text('Go to page 2'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = '/page2';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<Controller>();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            // Obx technically isn't needed for this example because 
            // Page2 builds after the value is updated
            child: Obx(
              () => Text(controller.controllerText
                  .value), 
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Get.back(),
            child: Text('Go to page 1'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your TextFormField with a Form widget.
Then create a form key of type GlobalKey and initialise it in the initState function of the Stateful widget.

in the `key` property of `Form` widget, use this GlobalKey.

in the TextFormField widget, use the `onSaved` property to pass a function to save the value of the form field wherever you want. Only after you call onSaved is the data ever saved anywhere, so you need to use this to save the data to the _phoneNumberController variable in your Getx Controller.

Right now, the data is not being saved and the controller is null, that's why it throws an exception when you call argumentData. its value is `null` because the _phoneNumberContoller text value is also null.

Sorry id the formatting is bad, I'm using my phone to type this.

Answer (score 0):

First Screen

```
 var data = {
        "vale": "x"    
      };
 Get.offAllNamed('/home', parameters: data);   // pass your value in parameters
```

Second Screen

```
  String s = Get.parameters['vale'].toString(). // here you will get 'x'
```